# Convert a transition line chart to D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've been working on building a variation of [Bostock's chained transitions](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818) example on v4 for awhile now. I have it working with no errors, but I can't get the area block to render correctly.

I believe I'm possibly not referencing the data correctly.  Maybe my syntax is incorrect with the call to area or d[city]?  I know that changed in version 4.

I'm also reading the data into a variable named area instead of line, as I want it to be an area chart.

Here is the basic code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var city = "New York",
    parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y%m%d');

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var area = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(yScale(yScale.domain()[0]))
    .y1(d => yScale(d.city))
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d["New York"] = +d["New York"];
    d["San Francisco"] = +d["San Francisco"];
  });

  xScale.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

  /*svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);*/

svg
    .selectAll('.area')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'area')
    .attr('d', area);
    /*.style('stroke', (d, i) => ['#FF9900', '#3369E8'][i])
    .style('stroke-width', 2)
    .style('fill', (d, i) => ['#FF9900', '#3369E8'][i])
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.5);*/

  svg.append("text")
      .datum(data[data.length - 1])
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(city);

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

  /*var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input[value=\"San Francisco\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);
  }, 2000);*/

  function change() {
    //clearTimeout(timeout);

    city = this.value;

    // First transition the line & label to the new city.
    var t0 = svg.transition().duration(750);
    t0.selectAll(".area").attr("d", area);
    t0.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", transform).text(city);

    /*Then transition the y-axis.
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; }));
    var t1 = t0.transition();
    t1.selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
    t1.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", transform);
    t1.selectAll(".y.axis").call(yAxis);*/
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d[city]) + ")";
  }
});
```

[And a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etyppc0t/) (though I'm not sure if the tsv file is being read properly).

Hopefully someone can spot the problem, as it compiles fine for me but displays nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major issue in the code:

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(yScale(yScale.domain()[0]))//incorrect as the extent is not defined
    .y1(d => yScale(d.city))
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));
```

Instead make it:

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y1((d) => yScale(d[city]))
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5))
```

Another problem

```
svg
    .selectAll('.area')
    .data(data) <--- it should be datum since you making a single path
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'area')
    .attr('d', area);
```

instead should be:

```
svg
    .append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'area')
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr('d', area);
```

Later when you set the extent set y0

```
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; }));
area.y0(yScale(yScale.domain()[0]));
```

Other trivial fixes in the transition.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xula8LkgYpZyVHR4abuI?p=preview)

Comment: Appreciate both the correct result and your taking the time to explain the changes.  This works perfectly.